# Calling a WP Plugin Function's Variable in Theme Template

Tags: theme-development, themes

Okay, my last question was closed because they said it wasn't about WordPress, even though it WAS about WordPress - lol. But, I think I have a better way of asking.

My WORDPRESS plugin function has a variable I'm trying to call in my theme template. The variable is $import_time and the function class is class_wpp_property_import

I'm not the plugin developer so I can't edit that file without it being erased.

I'm trying to figure out how to call this variable.

Comment: The question is about the WP Property plugin, and its data and classes, _that_ is what was off topic. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here, and not in this stacks scope. You can't ask for dev support for 3rd party plugins and themes here.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Specifically the section at the bottom titled _"questions concerning third party plugins and themes."_. Nobody said the question was unrelated to WordPress, it just doesn't fit within this stacks scope, this isn't an appropriate place to ask it. You can't ask dev support questions about 3rd party plugins here

Comment: I wasn't asking for 3rd party support. AT ALL. I'm sorry for naming the plugin. I'm simply trying to figure out how to call a variable. Plenty of other topics involving plugins. And very similar questions to mine in the searches.

Comment: You ***are*** asking for support developing using a 3rd party plugiin, you're asking how to retrieve data from a 3rd party plugin named WP Property, specifically from a class it contains named `class_wpp_property_import`. This question is off topic and not in this stacks scope. If you have other questions that are also off topic but not closed, that is not a reason to keep yours open, but I'll happily accept links so that they can be closed ( closing questions is done by volunteers, we can't catch every single question ).

Comment: If you disagree with the rule, and think it should be changed, you need to open a question on the meta stack and explain why your question about accessing data in a 3rd party plugin is not a question about a 3rd party plugin. The question is not in this stacks scope. This is not an appropriate place to ask it, you should ask elsewhere.

Comment: And to clarify further, I understand you are not trying to modify the WP Property plugin, but are doing work in your theme. 3rd party plugin dev support is not just modifying a 3rd party plugin, it's anything that requires knowledge of that plugin. That includes how to use it, modifying how it works with filters, questions about its functions and classes, etc. We are not a place to ask for developer help with 3rd party plugins/themes/services.